# What is functor bias?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

Following up from [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses), I have come across 'right biased functor' and 'left biased functor'. I have tried to do some research on my own, but I am still failing to understand the difference between both, and what functor bias even is.

Can someone please give an overview of what functor bias is, the difference between right bias and left bias, along with any examples of how this would be useful? It would be great if Scala could be used for the examples.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the word "functor" ended up used in such radically different ways in different communities. C++ "functors" are not Standard ML "functors" are not Scala/Haskell/category-theory "functors".

Answer (score 4):

Functor in scala isn't quite the same thing as what they call that in C++. It is a category with an operation like

```
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
```

that turns `F[A]` into `F[B]` given a transformer from `A` to `B`.

For example, an `Option` is a functor, that applies the transformation to the inner value when it is defined. A `List` is a functor, that applies the transformer to each element, etc.

Now, consider, something like `Either[A, B]`. Suppose, we wanted to define a functor for that. It takes two type parameters, but `Functor` only has one, so we have to choose on which the `Functor` will operate. It is common to use `Either` in a way, where `Right` is the default case, and `Left` is an exception (an error condition). So, it is natural, to consider it *right-biased*:

```
  def eitherFunctor[T] = new Functor[Either[T, ?]] {
     def map(fa: Either[T, A])(f: A => B): Either[T, B] = fa match {   
        case Right(a) => Right(f(a))
        case Left(t) => Left(t)
     }
  }
```

This works kinda like `Option.map`: when `Either` is a `Right`, it applies the transformer, otherwise, just returns the `Left` untouched. Thus, it can be said that `Either` is a right-biased functor, because it only operates on its right side.

Comment: Thanks, makes much more sense. I was trying to play with the code you provided and was having a lot of trouble with compiling using an IDE or even with SBT via the command line. I figure it may be because we did not override `map` as the compiler would have expected? Also, wouldn't we need to specify our other type parameters like `?`, `A`, and `B` in `eitherFunctor` where `T` is specified?